# Is there still any hope that the GCH could be equivalent to some large cardinal axiom?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Is there still any hope that the GCH could be equivalent to some large cardinal axiom?

Even a simple yes or not answer will be fine. Thanks!!

Comment: I am not sure to understand the negative vote. I am not a mathematician, so please be kind.

Comment: The negative vote was likely a response to your phrasing.  If the answer was "yes", then this would likely be considered a "soft question", while it is not tagged as such.  That being said, Asaf's answer makes it sound like "soft question" is not an appropriate tag.

Comment: @AWalker Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

The term "large cardinals" has no explicit and well-defined meaning, but it's general meaning is an additional axiom which is strictly stronger in consistency than $\sf ZFC$, that is some $\varphi$ such that $\sf ZFC+\varphi$ can prove the consistency of $\sf ZFC$.

On the other hand, $\sf ZFC+GCH$ is equiconsistent with $\sf ZFC$ so it is not a large cardinal axiom per se.

(To slightly elaborate on the above meaning of no well-defined meaning, $0^\#$ is considered a large cardinal axiom, but it really just says that a certain real number exists; or a Jonsson cardinal which is not even an inaccessible one, but its existence implies that inaccessible cardinals do exist. Both these, and more, are considered large cardinal axioms despite not being directly related to inaccessible cardinals and so.)

Comment: Asaf, I am not sure to understand your answer: L=V is also independent of ZFC but the axiom $\exists 0^\#$ implies $V \ne L$. Why can not the same happen for GCH? (I might be missing something obvious!)

Comment: julian, the existence of $0^\#$ implies *so much more* than just $V\neq L$. It implies that there are very very large cardinals in $L$. In fact every $\kappa$ which is a cardinal in $V$ is all the type of large cardinality which is consistent with $L$ when looking at $\kappa$ in $L$. (So for example, $L$ thinks that $(\aleph_1)^V$ is weakly-compact, and much more.)

Comment: Please bear in mind that I am light years behind you in your knowledge and intuitions, so my questions usually aim much lower than what you think (but thanks for thinking that I'm aiming higher!). What I meant is that "$V=L?$" is indeed independent of ZFC but you can find a large cardinal axiom (such as $\exists 0^\#$) that is equivalent to  "$V=L?$" being true or false (in this case, false). So, could the same in principle happen with GCH?

Comment: julian, large cardinal axioms are commonly axioms which imply the consistency of $\sf ZFC$, not axioms which are equiconsistent with $\sf ZFC$. Whereas $\sf ZFC+V=L$ or $\sf ZFC+GCH$ are equiconsistent with $\sf ZFC$ itself; if we assume that $\sf ZFC+\exists 0^\#$ then we can prove the consistency of $\sf ZFC$ (and much much more than that). This is not equivalent to just $\sf V\neq L$ or something like that, it's a lot stronger.

Comment: Asaf: thanks  for pointing the difference, I thought that $\exists 0^\#$ was a large cardinal axiom. So, let me read and think more about it to see if I need to reframe the question.

Comment: sorry, I just realized my comment was wrong!

Comment: julian, that's fine. No one died because of a wrong comment... on m.SE anyway. ;-)

Comment: haha, but I always get it wrong!!! (dont worry, I take it easy)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there was *ever* any hope that the GCH would be equivalent to a large cardinal axiom.  There was once a hope that CH or its negation would be *implied* by a large cardinal axiom, but this was dashed by the Levy–Solovay theorem and its generalizations, which say that large cardinals are preserved by "small" forcings such as the usual ones to force CH and not CH.

Comment: That's a good argument.

Comment: @Asaf I figured that the hope that large cardinals might settle CH might be what the OP was thinking of, although your answer is at least as relevant to the question as phrased.

Comment: Well, some forcing axioms *may* turn up being equiconsistent to supercompact cardinals... that would be a hoot. And those usually settle $\sf CH$.

Comment: @TrevorWilson thanks, that answers the question.

Comment: @Asaf  I suppose you could consider forcing axioms as saying that $\omega_2$ is a large cardinal

Comment: @julianfernandez I'm glad to have helped

Comment: @Trevor: Yes, I suppose one could think about that this way. I need to check under my bed for inner models for supercompact cardinals, they usually hide there and that would probably solve these questions! I mean, you can't rule out anything until you've checked... and it might be there!

Comment: Well, no inner model for supercompact cardinals under my bed. Only dust and fur from my cat rolling around. You should check under your bed too, it might be there.

Comment: @Asaf The mice we are looking for are non-domestic, so they won't be under your bed :-)

Comment: I live in the desert, you know. They might get into the city to look for food and end up under my bed. But alas, they're not there!

Comment: @Asaf I hope they have a good enough iteration strategy to escape your cat

Comment: Hey kids, stop fighting! (an old men's advice)

Comment: Trevor: Oh yeah, they have well-founded tree that they can escape through! :-) @julian: We're making large cardinal jokes...

Comment: too much testosterone here!

Comment: ok, sorry, I didnt get it :)

Comment: @Asaf I need to work on my mouse-related jokes.  There must be a lot more...

Comment: @julianfernandez That's okay, I'm not sure I get our jokes either :)

Comment: @Trevor: You have until two weeks from now!